# Should Christians be against the death penalty?

Tags: justice, civil-government

Christians go to great lengths to get the government to outlaw abortion--something that I personally would support. Though I see support from Christianity against abortion almost as unwavering, the support of death row inmates right to live seems to be a more contentious issue.

So my question is if Christianity holds human life to have intrinsic human value should this not apply to the death row inmate as well as the unborn baby?

Comment: Comments were heading off topic. Should be another question or head to chat.

Comment: I know this is an aging question, but since it floated up for other reasons can we get a few tweaks on it so it is more clearly about extant Christianity rather than using "shouldn't we" as the main hook?

Comment: Related: [What sort of Christians are proponents of just war?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/17064)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While many Christians are against the death penalty, there is also biblical sanction for it. Genesis 9:6 commands the killing of those who commit murder-

> He who sheds a man's blood, by man shall shall his blood be shed.

For many fundamentalists, such a clear case for the death penalty means that the death penalty should thus be supported.

The key question, however, is whether this is to Noah or for all time.

The Catholic Church in particular has done a great job of cultivating a "culture of life" within the church, and has thus found this scripture to be primarily about the sanctity of the life taken. Stances against abortion and euthanasia are harmonized with the death penalty, reflecting what Catholics declare us the nature of God- the creator and sustainer of life.  Governments are thus authorized, but not compelled to take action. (And, in any case, the death penalty is usually restricted to certain kinds if murder now)

Comment: Not that the Catholic Church appears to have a whole lot of say over the morality that goes in to laws any more, but as far as I know the death penalty is only permissible in cases where it would be impossible to protect society from the person involved.  I remember Sam Brownback quoted the Catechism on this pretty much verbatim when asked at a primary debate back in 2007, I thought that was pretty awesome.

Comment: But what about when (I don't have the exact line of scripture memorized, but I assume you probably do) the bible (NT) says, "**turn the other cheek**," and "**vengence is mine sayeth the Lord**?"  Also, "**let he who is without sin cast the first stone**."

Comment: @user1477388 In those verses God teaches how individuals should behave. This is not a teaching on how governments must operate. The difference is very significant.

Comment: @Narnian I am not sure I understand the difference between individuals being forbidden to commit murder, but governments (which are comprised of individuals; i.e. Presidents, Cheifs of Staff, etc.) are allowed to commit murder?

Comment: Because God delegates his authority to governments to carry out actions for the civil order.

Comment: @user1477388 Murder and Capital Punishment are very different things.  One takes the life of a person out of anger, rage, greed, or something like that.  The other assigns punishment without emotion for a crime that was committed.  Life is precious indeed.  If someone takes the life of another, that crime is so grievous and that life that he took so precious that he forfeits his own life for what he done.

Comment: @AffableGeek Where does it state this in the new testament?  Or, is this just an opinion?

Comment: @Narnian The message, "vengence is mine sayeth the Lord" seems pretty straightforward.  Do you have any biblical (NT) passages that would support your stance or is it just your personal opinion?  I agree, it's logical to kill off people in society who are evil murderers, but is it of faith?

Comment: That would be an excellent question to pose.  It is pretty common doctrine amongst many evangelicals, and I'm pretty sure I know where it comes from (Pilate, I'm looking at you!) but it's worth asking

Comment: @user1477388 Indeed, it does.  Yet, we are not talking about vengeance, but about justice.  God has established governments to execute justice.  This began in Genesis 9, where God says that whoever sheds the blood of man, by man shall his blood be shed, for in the image of God has God made man.  Also, in 1 Peter 2:13ff, God asserts that governments are there to punish evildoers.  So, there is no contradiction.  God's word emphatically and clearly establishes capital punishment as valid.  It is not murder--it is justice.

Comment: @Narnian  Sorry to keep these comments going, but as to "justice," so is "**an eye for an eye**."  But, Jesus was to have specifically command to instead "turn the other cheek."  I just don't see anywhere where Jesus said, "oh, yeah, and governments can exact justice on evil-doers."  You know?

Comment: @user1477388 Jesus may very well have said this.  However, the writers of the Gospel did not record this for us.  Jesus' teachings on this obviously did not contradict the rest of Scripture.  It is inappropriate to require Jesus to repeat everything from the Old Testament just to make sure it is valid.  Jesus used the Old Testament and validated it Himself, so we can take the Bible as a whole.  However, even in the New Testament (1 Peter 2), the role of government is affirmed.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose it is emphatic “no”. This is because we cannot bring moral equivalency between abortion and the death penalty. Both these issues are circumstantially different to each other. One is about an innocent baby’s life being taken in the womb and other a convicted murderer being executed. A baby in the womb has committed no crime.

It is inhuman not to protect the life of an innocent baby in the womb, and also it is necessary that the perpetrators of the most heinous of crimes should be executed. Being pro-life does not necessitate being anti-death in all circumstances. If one person murders another person, the just penalty is to end the life of the murderer. This actually upholds the value of life. Anyone who violates life in premeditated murder should be put to death – proclaiming clear support for the value of life.

It is entirely consistent to believe that the life of an innocent baby in the womb should be protected while believing that the perpetrators of the most heinous of crimes should be executed.

However, the death penalty should be, and in most cases is, employed only with the most evil of crimes. Some courts of law award this penalty in cases which are categorised as rarest of the rare.

Answer (score 7):

God not only allows for the death penalty, but specifically prescribes it--and it is not because life is *not* sacred, but because it *is*.

> “Whoever sheds the blood of man,
>       by man shall his blood be shed, for God made man in his own image.  Genesis 9:6 ESV

Specifically, if someone murders another, his crime is so heinous that God declares he has forfeited his own life.  The emphasis is on the sanctity of the life he took--not on the life of the taker.  He has sinned against God in doing so, and it is God who requires the penalty be paid.  It is important to note that this law precedes the Law of Moses and is thus not part of that covenant.  It is, therefore, fully applicable today.

Secondly, in the law of Moses, God also prescribes the death penalty for rape.  Again, it is such a heinous, horrible, despicable offense against the sanctity of the life of the woman, that God punishes the crime severely.  It is, again, that God holds the life of the victim as sacred that He requires the forfeiture of the life of the perpetrator.  This law is within the Law of Moses which was part of God's covenant with the Jews, so this could be seen as a pattern to follow rather than a prescription to institute in any nation.

Thus, there is no contradiction in supporting capital punishment while being against abortion.  Both positions recognize the sanctity of life.  The Pro-Life position recognizes that the life of the innocent child begins at conception and deems that no one has the right to end this life.

Capital Punishment recognizes the sanctity of the life of the victim and sees that taking the life of an innocent person is such a grave offense, that the highest of penalties is required.  From a biblical perspective, rape could legitimately be seen as rising to the same level of gravity and requiring the same penalty.

As a note, the American justice system is set up on the idea of life, liberty, and the pursuit of happiness.  A minor offense is punished by a restriction of one's pursuit of happiness--some of their money is forfeited.  A graver offense is punished by a restriction of one's liberty--they spend time behind bars, lose their driver's license, or something like that.  The gravest offenses may be punished with the taking of the criminal's life.

So, there are inalienable rights with which each individual is endowed by God.  However, a person may forfeit those rights to varying degrees.

Therefore, a Christian can justifiably be in favor of the death penalty *because* life is sacred.

Comment: Please see my comment (http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/15213/4576) to AffableGeek's answer; curious to know what you think.  Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

In [Romans 13:4](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%2013:4&version=KJV), Paul says:

> But if thou do that which is evil, be afraid; for he [government] beareth not the sword in vain: for he is the minister of God, a revenger to execute wrath upon him that doeth evil.

The government is thinking of the good of its population when executing capital punishment.  This is supported with statistics as well:  **About 71 lives are saved** for the execution of every murderer during the year (I read this in a paper--the source was [Kirchgässner, Gebhard. *Econometric Estimates of Deterrence of the Death Penalty: Facts or Ideology?*](http://ideas.repec.org/p/usg/econwp/201115.html), p. 448).

Capital punishment actually saves lives--the way God intended.

Comment: Hi Peter, welcome to Christianity.SE.  That's a very interesting idea, but it doesn't actually represent a Christian perspective.  We look for doctrinal answers to questions here, whereas yours appears to be derived more from a political and economic perspective.  As such, it's off-topic for Christianity.SE.  Please have a look at our FAQ (there's a link at the top) to clarify what we look for in questions and answers here.  Would you mind either editing your answer to present a doctrinal perspective of some sort or deleting it?  Thanks, and again welcome to our community.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: That's an improvement, though it would be better still if you provided a chapter and verse, and preferably a link. (You can find multiple Bible editions online at www.biblegateway.com, for example.  It's commonly used for citations here.)

Comment: I looked up the cited paper. It actually argues that the asserted figure (from a WSJ article) is *not* supported by the evidence. Moreover, the author acknowledges that even if it were true, there would still be substantial moral questions to answer.